# Why is my if block not getting executed in my C program?

Tags: c, string

Why is the `if` block not executed in the code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("----------------------------------< Welcome >----------------------------------\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------- to -------------------------------------\n");
    printf("-------------------- Temperature Convertor and Vice-Versa ---------------------\n");
    printf("-------------------( Press enter button at prompt to exit )--------------------\n");
    int i = 0;
    
    const char inp[4];
    printf("Do you want to Convert From Fahrenheit to Celsius:\n");
    scanf("%s",inp);
    printf("%s",inp);
    if(inp == "Yes" || inp == "yes" || inp == "y")
    {
        const char *temp1;
        printf("Enter the Temperature in Fahrenheit:\n");
        scanf("%s",temp1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the Code:

```
----------------------------------< Welcome >----------------------------------
-------------------------------------- to -------------------------------------
-------------------- Temperature Convertor and Vice-Versa ---------------------
-------------------( Press enter button at prompt to exit )--------------------
Do you want to Convert From Fahrenheit to Celsius:

yes
yes
--------------------------------
Process exited after 19.01 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Please don't use an image for the output. Could you post it here ?

Comment: "*`inp == "Yes"`*" that is not the way to compare "strings" (aka `0`-terminated `char`-arrays) in C.

Comment: I'm new to C but I know Python a lot

Comment: I'm doing it as a side language project

Comment: Then it's about time you get one at least some tutorial or other learning source. Google should help yoo to find what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the `strcmp` problem which has been addressed in an other answer there are three problems in this piece of code:

```
const char* temp1;
printf("Enter the Temperature in Fahrenheit:\n");
scanf("%s",temp1);
```

- you don't want `const` because the value you want to get from the user is not ... constant
- `temp1` is an uninitialized pointer that points nowhere
- you don't need a string here but you want the user enter a *number*

So you want actually something like this:

```
float tempFahrenheit;
printf("Enter the Temperature in Fahrenheit:\n");
scanf("%f", &tempFahrenheit);

float tempCelsius = ...   // I let you write the rest of the code yourself
```

If you want get a string from the user and convert that to a number you might want something like this:

```
float tempFahrenheit;
char inputstring[20];   // max length of string is 20
printf("Enter the Temperature in Fahrenheit:\n");
scanf("%s", inputstring);
sscanf(temp, "%f", &tempFahrenheit); 
float tempCelsius = ...   // I let you write the rest of the code yourself
```

Comment: @Armaan don't put code in comments. It's unreadable and therefore pointless. [Edit] your question instead, then delete the pointless comments.

Comment: Is this possible to recreate in C or not?

Comment: Yes, of course it it possible. But be aware that you can't just translate code from python to C without knowing the basics of the C language. C an python are _very_ different languages.

Comment: @Armaan that question is far too long to answer. What about googling "python vs c"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the if block is skipped, because the condition is never true.
In C, you can't just do `inp == "Yes"`. You have to do `strcmp` and compare the strings.

```c
if (strcmp(inp, "Yes") == 0 || strcmp(inp, "yes") == 0 || strcmp(inp, "y") == 0)
```

Like so, but in order to use `strcmp()`, you have to include string.h

```c
#include <string.h>
```

Apart from that, there is some other problem in your code.

```
        const char* temp1; // this should be int or float value, not const char.
        printf("Enter the Temperature in Fahrenheit:\n");
        scanf("%s",temp1);
```

And `scanf("%s", temp1);` will not work because temp1 is undefined.

Comment: I have used const char because I want it to take string values and then convert it to int.

Comment: Will it help me?

Comment: _"have used const char because I want it to take string values and then convert it to int"_: huh (??!)

Comment: Yeah but why are you like teasing me on every mistake I did? I am a newbie in C

Comment: I saw that on a website

Comment: I don't know if in C we have this feature or not but in Python we have it

Comment: Which website? And what feature? C is not Python, it's _very_  different.

Comment: I want to do it cause I want it to exit on pressing enter as you can see in my printf statements

Comment: I want to break the loop I will make in future every time user presses enter key at prompt

Answer (score 1):

```c
if(inp == "Yes" || inp == "yes" || inp == "y")
```

The reason why this doesn't work is because of pointers.

The compiler creates a string for "Yes", "yes" and "y" where each has it's own address in memory.

`inp` is another pointer from your program, so what the `if` does is simply comparing the pointers, which are obviously never the same. It does NOT compare the content the pointers are pointing to, as the C compiler wouldn't even know what it exactly points to, and how to compare it. So you have to use `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct compare string method.
`if(inp == "Yes" || inp == "yes" || inp == "y")`

You need to use `strcmp()` and `include <string.h>`.

This is correct way to compare string:

`if(strcmp( inp,"Yes" ) == 0 || strcmp( inp,"yes" ) || strcmp( inp,"y") == 0 )`